# Why the same code goes with different result

Tags: ios

I just pull the code of my team. But why it run well with the other simulator, and my device it always goes crash. I also use the **xcode 7.2**, which is the same as the other, and the code are similar, and run with the same simulator (Iphone6). But when I go to the **abcViewController**, it goes crash.

It says:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fb5e2409200>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'StepDetailViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
```

The problem is not the code, so I don't put it here. Anyone know why this happen?

Comment: Did you have the view controller with identifier 'StepDetailViewController'?

Comment: Yes, I've already set all. The app run well with the other device in the other pc. But mine, it goes crash

Answer (score 0):

The error message already includes what's wrong:

```
'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fb5e2409200>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'StepDetailViewController'
```

Your storyboard file (probably `Main.storyboard`) has a `UIViewController` which doesn't have an identifier. Open the storyboard, click on the `UIViewController` and enter `StepDetailViewController` in the **Storyboard ID** textfield in the **identity inspector** on the right side of your XCode window.

Comment: As I say, It run well with the other simulator in the other PC. But in mine, it goes crash.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't crash on another simulator, but it's obvious why it crashes on yours. Maybe somehow that identifier was removed. Should be easy to fix though.

Comment: No, I've already test when I sit next to him, both of we use the same code that just pull from Git. But why my simulator goes crash, and the other simulator doesn't

Comment: I really don't know, but as you're not willing to fix the obvious issue your project has, I can't and won't help you any further. My only advice: Fix that issue and test again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure of following things in Interface Builder:

- In the Attribute inspector, make sure your project is selected in the
  Module field
- In the Identity section of the Attribute Inspector your
  Storyboard ID should be 'StepDetailViewController'

If you are using Git, it might be a good idea to check the files are on the .gitignore file, if the above points don't help, your problem is probably in one of the added files.